# Is there any inbuilt subscribe to change in time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In JavaScript is there any built in functionality to subscribe to change in time?

Something which can use a callback function like -

```
time.hours.subscribe (Date.getHourChnage(), callback);
```

I've written this small code to do that, but was wondering if there's any cleaner way to do it. Here's what I have:

```
let lastMin = null;

$interval(function() {
 let d = new Date(),
     m = d.getMinutes;

 if(m !== lastMin){
   console.log('change in minute');
   lastMin = m;
 }

},1000);
```

Comment: There is no Javascript built-in functionality to do that.  One could write a function to calculate the time until the next hour change and then use `setTimeout()` for that particular time and avoid polling every second.

Comment: @jfriend00 is right. Also, why using let from ES6 standards here?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar : what's wrong with let? Isn't it more explicit than just using a var.

Comment: @Rohan correct, I am not used to see it, thats all